# Latest Version of Install4j 10.0

Tags: install4j

We are using latest version of install4j 10.0 but we are facing issues while writing code in editor instead of writing chars in front of cursor it will write somewhere in editor and this case is observed while we copy paste code to editor.
Can you help us.

Comment: Can you show what you mean (like in some screenshots)?

Comment: Please contact support@ej-technologies.com with a screenshot.